# Asyncio: Detecting never awaited coroutines beforehand

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.10

When `await` is not expressed in a coroutine call, asyncio shows

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited
```

The problem is that this print is easily missable in production environment. It's also difficult when your console shows other application logs.

It's a critical, bug prone warning that simply goes unnoticed sometimes.

Is there a way to detect these errors at **compile time**?

If not, is there a way to raise this warning **like an error** or at least improve its report in order to not miss it?

Answer (score 1):

You can always elevate all warnings to errors by passing the `-W error` switch to the Python interpreter itself.
Other than that, the behavior can be modified programatically with the `warnings` module, from the code - either elevating them to errors, or making them being properly logged:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Comment: I'll take a look. It would only be interesting if I could elevate just this type of RuntimeWarning, otherwise it would make our error logs even more polluted.